# Is it possible to use an iPhone as an external encrypted drive accessible by iOS and any unix-based OS?

Tags: iphone, ios, hard-drive, unix, encryption

Is it possible to use an iPhone in a way that can be encrypted and accessed by both iOS and any unix based OS as an external  drive? Even if additional software or tinkering is necessary in either system.

Reasoning is that I always carry it with me and it seems a much more secure alternative to uploading sensitive files to Dropbox so I can access them by the phone and any other computer.

---

~~I will be cross-posting this question to several other subject related stack communities in the hopes to obtain a good answer. I haven't been around here for a while; let me know if this is not kosher and I'll remove them~~ *Edit: I've been advised against this, so moot now.*

Comment: Cross-posting is not good etiquette on the Stack Exchange network: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

I think this is a good question for this site though.

Comment: Ok. Will delete the others. Tx!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "as an external drive". Are you saying that you want to use the iPhone as an externel drive for an iPad (i.e. another iOS device)? Also what do you mean by "unix-based" OS - it doesn't really make any sense. Be specific if you mean Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, macOS or whatever.

Comment: @jksoegaard: When I say iOS, I mean the same iPhone, the goal is for the files to be encrypted separately from the regular OS, while retaining the ability to see them in my phone. When I say _unix-based_ I mean just that. In reality, any desktop OS should serve my purpose: spinning out a VM is a quick thing to do and I'm ready to adapt my workflow.

Comment: Sorry, but "just that" doesn't really cut it. Linux is for example not based on Unix as such - however some might call it "unix-based" because it is "unix-like". It is very hard to help you answer your question, when you cannot specify which operating systems you want it to work with. We have no clue if you want it to work together with SCO UnixWare, AIX or NetBSD.

Comment: @jksoegaard I come in peace, my friend ;). You are righty about unix-like vs unix-based. As per the OS, I tried to explain that it doesn't matter to me, whatever is easiest to make work together, but if you want one, let's just say Debian.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, yes. There are a huge number of file manager apps out there. The trick is to find one which is (a) secure and (b) provides a webdav server so you can access the files on the device from other machines on the network (via a web browser or other webdav client).

I use [Files](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/files-document-pdf-reader/id294150896?mt=8) by Olive Toast, which certainly fits your second criterion. Another one which looks like it would is [EZ Server](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/ez-server-file-transfer/id1062240259?mt=8) by Lisa Burns.

Regarding security, it depends what you're looking for. Do you want the files stored in encrypted storage on your iOS device? That's how iOS works for everything. Do you want them protected by a password? Isn't your iOS passcode enough? Do you want the webdav server to support https? Probably only necessary if you're using public Wi-Fi networks.